# return if a user exist in database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I have a MySQL database where I have a userid and a password column. Each of them has the value "mads". I have some problems that I have been struggling with some days now, because I didn't program so long time. I have a JSP page where I have my form and a servlet who makes the connection to the MySQL database. When i put in mads in userid and password I get always the message "You are not valid". That means it dosent give me the answer "The user is valid", as I would like to. I would not like to create a user, I would just like to check if the user exist in the database. My JSP and servlet code is here: I hope somebody can help me, because I really don't know what is wrong.

Best Regards Mads

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Validation</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* border-radius er rundt hjørner på input..*/
input[type=text] {padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius:5px;}
input[type=text]:focus{border-color:yellow;}
input[type=password] {padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius:5px;}
input[type=password]:focus{border-color:yellow;}
input[type=submit] {padding: 5px 15px; background:#ccc; border:0 none; cursor:pointer; webkit-border-radius:5px; border-radius: 5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br>
        <center>
            <h1>Please enter user name and password</h1>

            <form name="frm" action="LoginValidation" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="user">
                <input type ="password" name="pass">
                <input type="submit" value="Check" class="submit">
            </form>
        </center>
</body>
```

And My Servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
//import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LoginValidation"})
public class Validation extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ServletConfig config;

    public void init (ServletConfig config) 
    throws ServletException{
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException,IOException {


        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dblogin";
        Connection connection = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
        String password =request.getParameter("password");
        ////and your select statement 

        try{
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid = ? AND password = ?";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, userid);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

             Statement s = connection.createStatement();
             rs =preparedStatement.executeQuery();

         ////if there are next ib rs so you have a user by this id and password 
             if(rs.next()) {
               out.println("The user is valid");
             }
             else {
               out.println("You are not valid");
             }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("The exception is" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You SQL request is bad, you probably need `SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid = ? AND password = ?`

Comment: Also, how can you check user input with `String userid = new String("");` (same for password)?

Comment: Hello RC. Thanks for your quick answer. Hm that is a good question... so the code is not valid:?
`String userid = new String("");
String password = new String("");`

I need to find a way that checks for the input then?

Comment: You need to use the userId and password from the request in your query.

Comment: Is it something with `request.getQueryString()`? I don't how the syntax for it is. Is it the only thing I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable fix:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dblogin";
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String userid = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        try {
            // Load the database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
            //Add the data into the database
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid = ? AND password = ?";

            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, userid);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                // redirect or print but not both...
                out.println("The user is valid");
                // response.sendRedirect("index_true.jsp");
            } else {
                out.println("You are not valid");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is: " + e);
        } finally {
            // TODO: check for nullity
            rs.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Fixed:

- use request parameter to fetch a record from the DB
- execute the proper statement
- ...

(there might still be some issues, this was not tested)

Comment: " rs = preparedStatement.getResultSet();" should be changed to "rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();". getResultSet() will return null.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty string for `userid` and `password` , and you make a query by using this values , so it will return nothing

so you need first to take the `userid` and `password` from the user , then make the query by using this values , and if there are a result , so you have valid user

```
String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
String password =request.getParameter("password");
////and your select statment 
String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid = ? AND password = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, userid);
preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

 Statement s = connection.createStatement();
 rs =preparedStatement.executeQuery();

////if there are next ib rs so you have a user by this id and password 
if(rs.next()) {
  out.println("The user is valid");
}
else {
  out.println("You are not valid");
}
```

Comment: ok , first try to delete the other comments because it confused me , then try to print the userid and password in your doPost method , then tell me

Comment: and clearly that you will get null , because you write `userid` in request.getparametar , and in jsp you named it `name` : `<input type="text" name="user">` , so make it userid and also with password

Comment: I have deleted the comments now :-) If I run my java class code now I get an error:
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
type Status report
message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource. And my jsp site:
"You are not valid"

Comment: look i'm not good in jsp and servlet so forgive me i don't know this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

In the form the parameter name is user but in the servlet you are using getParameter("UserId")

Debugging the servlet code to check received parameters might be usefull in this case.

Also take in account previous comment on the correct select syntax and that you are passing empty strings are query parameters and you should use the request params and remove the result check since it is duplicate with the query itself..

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns no result. What you need to do is to set userId and password to the values send via post request.

```
 userid = request.getParameter("userid");
 password = request.getParameter("password");
```

And when you run the query, you won't be needing a loop if your usernames are unique (they should be).

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
        pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
    
    
    
    
    Validation
    
    /* border-radius er rundt hjørner på input..*/
    input[type=text] {padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius:5px;}
    input[type=text]:focus{border-color:yellow;}
    input[type=password] {padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius:5px;}
    input[type=password]:focus{border-color:yellow;}
    input[type=submit] {padding: 5px 15px; background:#ccc; border:0 none; cursor:pointer; webkit-border-radius:5px; border-radius: 5px;}

## Please enter user name and password

```
            <form name="frm" action="LoginValidation" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="userid">
                <input type ="password" name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Check" class="submit">
            </form>
        </center>
</body>

package jsp;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LoginValidation"})
public class Validation extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException,IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dblogin";
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
        String password =request.getParameter("password");
        response.setContentType("text/html");


        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid = ? AND password = ?";

            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, userid);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

             //Statement s = connection.createStatement();
             rs =preparedStatement.executeQuery();

             if(rs.next()) {
               out.println("The user is valid");
             }
             else {
               out.println("You are not valid");
             }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("The exception is" + e);

        }

    }
}
```